# Why do some Conan packages delete CMake Package information

Tags: c++, grpc, conan, yaml-cpp, catch2

I'm relatively new to Conan.  I'm trying to use packages provided by conan in a very natural cmake way...i.e. I don't want anything conan specific in the consuming library's `CMakeLists.txt`. I just want to `find_package` my dependency, `target_link_libraries` to it, and move on just like I could pre-conan. If the dependency did their cmake correctly, all transitive dependencies are handled automagically. Per this blog article: https://blog.conan.io/2018/06/11/Transparent-CMake-Integration.html it seems the way to do this is using the `cmake_paths` generator. I can make and consume packages with that generator no problem.

I'm now trying to comsume a number of third party libraries, namely `grpc`, `yaml-cpp`, and `Catch2`, however none of those packages work with the `cmake_paths` generator because as part of their package recipe they explicitly delete the cmake package configuration files.

See
https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/ce2f6b89606cc582ccabbb5420f18a29e705dae3/recipes/grpc/all/conanfile.py#L171

https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/ce2f6b89606cc582ccabbb5420f18a29e705dae3/recipes/catch2/2.x.x/conanfile.py#L97

https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/ce2f6b89606cc582ccabbb5420f18a29e705dae3/recipes/yaml-cpp/all/conanfile.py#L95-L96

I obviously haven't done an exhaustive search to see how many packages do this, I just find it hard to believe it's just a coincidence that the three libraries I want to pull in first are the only three that do this.

Is there a reason this is done? or is this a hold-over from times before the `cmake_paths` generator was a thing and should now be considered a bug?

In the blog article about transparent cmake integration, it states that one of the downsides of the `cmake_paths` generator is that transitive dependency information is *not*   propagated, but the only reason I can see that would be is because the CMake config modules are deleted as shown above--a major feature of what cmake does (especially modern CMake) is to manage those transitive dependencies. Why does conan seem to want to throw that information away?

Comment: That post old and many things changed (for better). Now there are better generators like [cmake_find_package](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/cmake_find_package.html) and [cmake_find_package_multi](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/cmake_find_package_multi.html) which provide `Findxxx.cmake` and `xxx-config.cmake`. They are enough for your case. In there future, for Conan 2.0, the generator [cmakedeps](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake/cmakedeps.html#cmakedeps) should be the default, but is available since 1.33 too.

Comment: This is a good article as well https://jfreeman.dev/blog/2019/05/22/trying-conan-with-modern-cmake:-dependencies/ although it still doesn't really answer the question I'm getting at here

Comment: `cmake_find_package` seems like a step backwards.  There's no need for conan to provide that because cmake already does (at least if the library author does the cmake right, which is the case for many open source libraries). From what I understand in conan 2.0 the `cmake_find_package` generator is going away as well. I did see the page you reference on `cmakedeps` and that seems like a step in the right direction.  The page isn't quite clear on how to use it though...if you have a good example I'd be interested in looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons why ConanCenter (not Conan, this is only a requirement of public packages in ConanCenter) is removing the packaged findxxx.cmake or xxxx-config.cmake files from packages are:

- Packages from ConanCenter should work from any other build system, not only CMake. Even if CMake is now used by a majority of devs (some surveys shows around 50-55%), there are still a lot of people using other build systems, MSBuild, Meson, Autotools, ec. Conan defines the information for consumers in its `package_info()` method, which is an abstraction that will work for any consumer build system. When this was not mandatory in ConanCenter, it resulted in many packages that only worked for CMake.
- It happens that some of the packaged cmake files can be problematic, and depending on how they are generated, they will not handle transitive dependencies as expected, and they can find transitive dependencies in the system instead of other Conan packages. This happens sometimes when an open source library doesn't have a modern and correct CMakeLists.txt and locates some dependencies in the system directly. Unfortunately the quality of CMakeLists.txt files out there is varying and they not always follow best practices.
- Conan handles binary configuration separately, to scale to support many different binary configurations (for example ConanCenter builds around 130 different binaries for each package version), so for example the Debug and Release packages are in separate locations. The native `find_package()` CMake files cannot handle this situation, so all users expecting to have multi-config setup (like Visual Studio and Xcode) will not manage to achieve this without the Conan generated .cmake files.

Again, this only applies to ConanCenter packages, because ConanCenter is trying to be as universal as possible (to support fairly all build systems) and to allow multi-configuration setups, while being as robust as possible given the complexities of the diverse ecosystem.
In any case, the modern `CMakeDeps` and `CMakeToolchain` experimental generators will achieve a transparent integration, they are already released in latest Conan 1.X and as those will be the ones that will survive in next 2.0, it is recommended to start trying them soon.